# Excel formula to calculate values based on other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got the following table:
[image]

I'm using the following formula in `column` `F` to get the sum of the values in `column` `E`: `=SUMIFS(E:E,C:C,LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT([@[Object Name]],LEN([@[Object Name]])-FIND("=",[@[Object Name]]))),4),A:A,INT([@[Result Time]]))` but it doesn't seem to work.

Evaluating the formula gives me the following result:
[image]

Can someone please take a took at the for

Comment: The result is not suprising. Your criteria range is column C (Object Name), while your criteria is only part of it. No clue what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @JvdV my criteria for column `C` is the first four letters after `=`. The formula `LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT([@[Object Name]],LEN([@[Object Name]])-FIND("=",[@[Object Name]]))),4)` retruns the first four values after `=`. separating the formulas works, but it doesn't when I use them together.

Comment: Put differently: If your range has values like: "ABC123" and you check if their value is "123". What would the result be? They would be `FALSE`....

Comment: @JvdV I'm trying to find if their value contains 123, and the calculate if it does

Comment: You'll have to then use a wildcard within your criteria. For example: `"*" & [following characters to end your strings with]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an object name of "T054", when they all appear to be "CELL=T054CID"... so no results are being returned.

What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Is there any reason you cannot just do:

```
=SUMIFS([3G_Traffic_CS],[Object Name],[@[Object Name]],[Result Time],[@[Result Time]])
```

[image]

You will also notice that I am referencing just the column cells within the table, rather than the entire column. This is more efficient and will prevent any extra values which appear under the table being counted (unlikely but not impossible).

**ALTERNATIVE (Using a Helper Column)**

Add a helper column which contains a trimmed value of the Object Name and compare to that:

```
=SUMIFS([3G_Traffic_CS],[Trimmed Object Name],[@[Trimmed Object Name]],[Result Time],[@[Result Time]])
```

[image]

**ANOTHER ALTERNATIVE (Using `FIND` and `SUMPRODUCT`)**

If you want to include any Object Name which *CONTAINS* your trimmed value, you can do this using the `FIND`function with `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    ([Result Time]=[@[Result Time]])*
    (ISNUMBER(
        FIND(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT([@[Object Name]],LEN([@[Object Name]])-FIND("=",[@[Object Name]]))),4),
            [Object Name]
        )
    ))*
    [3G_Traffic_CS]
)
```

[image]

**YET ANOTHER ALTERNATIVE (Using a Wildcard as per @Jvdv's comment)**

Again, this assumes that you want to include all Object Names which *CONTAIN* your trimmed site ID. Simply add a "*" to the start and end of your trimmed Object Name.

```
=SUMIFS([3G_Traffic_CS],
    [Object Name],
    CONCAT("*",
        LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT([@[Object Name]],LEN([@[Object Name]])-FIND("=",[@[Object Name]]))),4),
        "*"
    ),
    [Result Time],
    INT([@[Result Time]])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply. T054 is just one cell, there are others cells T055, T056, etc. I might have to end up using a helper column if I'm can't figure out a way, but I'd like to avoid that because sheet alrady takes too long to calculate.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you are trimming the Object Name at all? Why doesn't my first suggestion do what you want? Also, referencing just the table columns, rather than the entire column should help speed up calculation time.

Comment: The Object Name is really long with numbers at the end, but the different cells have their names, but cells at the same site will have the site ID i.e. T054, within the Object Name; I'm trying to sum the values of the cells at the same site i.e. all the cells in T054.

Comment: Ah ok. I see now. In that case I would probably suggest adding the "Site ID" as a helper column, and look at other ways of speeding up the calculation. That way, it makes it very clear how the "Total Traffic" formula works. And as a bonus, you can easily filter the table based on the Site ID if required.

Comment: The find and sum product solution is working like I inteded. Thanks for your help

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` would be slower than using a wildcard, but still a decent alternative +

Comment: For example: `=SUMIFS([3G_Traffic_CS],[Object Name],"*"&MID([@[Object Name]],FIND("=",[@[Object Name]]),4)&"*",[Result time],[@[Result time]])`

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the wildcard... not sure how much difference it will make to the speed. @JvdV If you would like to post your suggestion as an answer, I am happy to remove it from mine.

Comment: No, your answer is neat and complete! Keep it. As for speed....one will have to find out on a large dataset =)

Comment: @JvdV I like both of your suggestions and have learnt something from both of them. Thanks for your help